# Show Dataset value on a Textbox in a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC 5 with Razor.

I have a View with a Textbox and a Search button. On click of this Search button, a controller action returns a Dataset.

In the same View I have three more Textboxes where the values are to be shown. I want to show the Dataset values on these Textboxes.

The controller code is as below:

```
[HttpGet]
public DataSet Search(string EmpCode)
{
    DataSet ds = ExecuteSP("GetEmpDetails", staffCode);
    return ds;
}
```

The View markup is as below:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Details",FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <table style="border:none">
            <tr>
                <td style="border:none">Enter staff code</td>
                <td style="border:none">@Html.TextBox("empcode", "", new { width = "100" })</td>
                <td style="border:none"><input type="submit" value="Get Details" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
      <br /><hr />  
     <table id="tblEmpDetails" style="border:none">
         <tr>
             <td style="border:none; width:200px;text-align:left">Employee Name</td>
             <td style="border:none">@Html.TextBox("EmpName", "", new { @class = "ReadOnly", width = "200" })</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border:none;width:200px;;text-align:left">Designation</td>
             <td style="border:none;">@Html.TextBox("Designation", "", new { @class="ReadOnly", width = "100" })</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
             <td style="border:none; width:200px;;text-align:left">Department</td>
             <td style="border:none;">@Html.TextBox("Department", "", new { @class = "ReadOnly", width = "100" })</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

Comment: Don't you have a `Model` to bind things to?

Comment: A `DataSet` is a collection. You either need a loop to display textboxes for all items in the collection, or you need to return one item

Comment: @StephenMuecke Assume only one row is there in the DataSet.

Comment: This is where your value goes: `, ""`. You're setting it as an empty string. But I would highly recommend the use of a `Model`.

Comment: Then you need to return the first row (`DataSet` does not contain properties `EmpName`, `Designation` etc.) In any case, you need to define a view model, populate that view model with the properties of the first row and then declare that model in the view - `@model yourAssembly.yourModel`

Comment: @StephenMuecke How to bind Textboxes with ViewModel properties. Please illustrate with code that will really help.

Comment: If your model contains (say) `public string EmpName { get; set; }` then in the view use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmpName)` etc. Now you can post back your model to the controller - `public ActionResult Edit(yourModel model)`. And html `<table>` elements are for tabular data - not layout!

Comment: @StephenMuecke If you could post this as an Answer, I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a model that you can bind your view to, for example

```
public class EmployeeVM
{
  [Display(Name = "Name")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
  public string EmpName { get; set; }

  public string Designation { get; set; }
  ....
}
```

Then in you controller, initialize an instance of the view model (or a collection of the view models) and pass it to the view

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(string EmpCode)
{
    DataSet ds = ExecuteSP("GetEmpDetails", staffCode);
    EmployeeVM model = new EmployeeVM();
    // map the first row of the data set properties to the view model
    // or each row to a collection of view models
    return View(model);
}
```

And in the view

```
@model yourAssembly EmployeeWM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmpName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmpName)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmpName)
  ....
}
```